# Create constant from another constant

Tags: java

Today I saw something like this:

```
...
public class SomeClass {
    public static final int A_CONSTANT = SomeOtherClass.ANOTHER_CONSTANT;
...
```

Does this make sense? What is it good for? I wouldn't do it but I am just wondering since I didn't find anything about it

Comment: It would reduce the amount of code, if the constant is often used. So you have not to refer to `SomeOtherClass.ANOTHER_CONSTANT` but only to `A_CONSTANT`.

Comment: @IQV This could also be solved with a `static import`.

Comment: Maybe for some reason both values bust be the same but serve different purpose in both classes so that different names are desired.

Answer (score 7):

Things like this are easier to answer if you don't anonymize away the meaningful names.

```
public class InfinityStone {
    public static final int MAX_POWER = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
}
```

It's really a name change after all.  The meaning is the point. Sure, I just want to use a number but I want make my thinking clear each step of the way by using the best name I can come up with.  That way when things need to change the programmer that comes after me isn't looking at some weird number wondering why I chose it.

Why not just use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` everywhere? Because that name has limited meaning to my `InfinityStone` context. I'm trying to create a place where one model and one domain language dominates.  It's distracting to see an implementation detail like `Integer.MAX_VALUE` scattered about in there.

The longer I spend programming the more convinced I am that the best thing you can do for a design is give things good names.

Comment: Yup, this is it. Good names with good context are key in so many ways.